# How to plot two columns of a specific index range?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, indexing

I made a dataframe from a .txt file that has 2 columns. I have a specific indexing range (3751:6252) for which I want to plot column 1 (freq) vs column 2 (phase).

How can I do this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 

#open text file and save it as a df (dataframe)
textfile = pd.read_csv("RawPhaseData.txt", sep='\s+', skiprows= 2, header=None, names = ['freq', 'phase'])
#make the index equal to frequency
#textfile.set_index("freq", inplace=True)

p = textfile[3751:6252]
x = p['freq']
y = p['phase']
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Expecting a graph but nothing outputs.

Part of the results when I say print(p)

```
                  freq             phase
3751  0.55000000000000  -51.101839657065
3752  0.55004000000000  -51.251119837268
3753  0.55008000000000  -51.400516517531
3754  0.55012000000000  -51.550029980720
3755  0.55016000000000  -51.699660509792
3756  0.55020000000000  -51.849408387787
```

....

Part of the results when I say print(x)

```
3751    0.55000000000000
3752    0.55004000000000
3753    0.55008000000000
3754    0.55012000000000
3755    0.55016000000000
3756    0.55020000000000
3757    0.55024000000000
3758    0.55028000000000
3759    0.55032000000000
```

....

Part of the results when I say print(y)

```
3751    -51.101839657065
3752    -51.251119837268
3753    -51.400516517531
3754    -51.550029980720
3755    -51.699660509792
3756    -51.849408387787
3757    -51.999273897829
```

....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add %matplotlib inline after the import.

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` 
`%matplotlib inline`